# Not able to access lightning record page layouts in Salesforce 1 app

Tags: lightning, salesforce1-app, page-layout, inline-visualforce

We are working on to roll out Salesforce 1 mobile app for our users.In this process, we are stuck with one issue which is stopping users from accessing the record pages in the same way we access them in lightning.

A Little background: Our current solution is on Lightning, on few objects record page layouts we have embedded VF pages. To make them function in a better way we used Lightning pages 'Tab Panel' and created a new custom tab on the Lightning record pages, under this new tab we are tagging our VF page, with this we don't have any more inline VF pages on the standard page layouts.

[image]

But on the Salesforce 1 mobile app, we are seeing the layout is inhering its property from Standard Classic layout but not from the related lightning record page.

[image]

With this we are losing out custom tab which is holding the related VF page, the only way we are seeing is to add back the inline VF page back to standard layouts which users are not really comfortable with.

Is there any workaround to create a new tab under record layout in the path of Feed, Details and Related??

Even though it won't solve the complete problem, but one way I am seeing is to add the VF page under "Mobile Cards (Salesforce1 only)" section on the standard page layouts so this page will come under related list.  Is there any better way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

According to [this](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=lightning_app_builder_customize_lex_pages.htm&language=en_US&type=0) documentation:

> Lightning record, home, and utility bar pages available in: Lightning
>   Experience

And [this](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.salesforce1.meta/salesforce1/page_layouts_how_they_work_in_s1.htm) documentation, the mobile cards are the way to go.